# Build dataframe from results of a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe

How do I get the results of this query into a data frame. I have tried numerous example fixes to this problem, but none of them give me all 100 rows I am looking for. Thanks.

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

scores = df['clean_tweet']

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

for score in scores:
    print(score)
    ss = sid.polarity_scores(score)
    for k in sorted(ss):
        print('{0}: {1}, '.format(k, ss[k]), end='')
        print()

 # decide sentiment as positive, negative and neutral 
    if ss['compound'] > 0 : 
        print("Pos") 

    elif ss['compound'] < 0 : 
        print("Neg") 

    else : 
        print("Neutral")
```

Comment: You have tried numerous example fixes, but you're not sharing any of them here, especially the one(s) you thought should work. The code you've provide is also very much incomplete - what is in `df`? Probably just the texts you are looking to analyze, given that you pass them to `polarity_scores()`, so the name `scores` is probably just confusing? What part of the result do you need in a DataFrame? The text? The return values from `polarity_scores`? Your own valuation?

Comment: Please be more specific for e.g. instead of just dataframe specify pandas dataframe. Also try to put head of input and output, both actual and expected. This will help you get answered quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `df` in your example already contains all the texts you'd like to analyse in its `'clean_tweet'` column, something straightforward like:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

df = DataFrame([
    {'clean_tweet': 'this is a bad example'},
    {'clean_tweet': 'this is a really good one'}
])

sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

analyses = [
    {'clean_tweet': tweet, **sia.polarity_scores(tweet)}
    for tweet in df['clean_tweet']
]
result = DataFrame([
    {**analysis, 'score': 'Pos' if analysis['compound'] > 0
     else 'Neg' if analysis['compound'] < 0 else 'Neutral'}
    for analysis in analyses
])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
                 clean_tweet    neg    neu    pos  compound score
0      this is a bad example  0.538  0.462  0.000   -0.5423   Neg
1  this is a really good one  0.000  0.556  0.444    0.4927   Pos
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a new column, sentiment?
If yes, try this.

```
def sentiment_calculation(ss):
    score = ss['compound']
    if score > 0:
        return "Pos"
    elif score < 0:
        return "Neg"
    else:
        return "Neutral"

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":list(range(5)),
                   "clean_tweet":['I hate this movie', 'I love him', 'disgusting', 'love yo', 'Beautiful']})

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

polarity_scores = df['clean_tweet'].apply(sid.polarity_scores)
df['sentiment'] = polarity_scores.apply(sentiment_calculation)
```

The result is as follows.

[image]

You just change df as your df.